Calculating Inclusion Bayes Factors Across Different Outcome Variables
I'm conducting statistical analyses to determine the probability of observed data under various models, particularly examining whether models that include specific effects are more probable than those that do not, based on multiple criteria.
In my study, I'm dealing with four distinct outcome variables (representing different personality traits: Y1, Y2, Y3, and Y4). For each of these outcomes, I've run three Bayesian linear regressions using the following models:

Model with predictor X1 only
Model with predictors X1 and X2
Model with predictors X1, X2, and their interaction

For each outcome, I have compared the models using individual Bayes Factors. Now, I'm exploring whether it is possible to compute a summary Bayes Factor that aggregates these comparisons across all outcomes.
Is there a methodology or approach to calculate an aggregated or inclusion Bayes Factor that spans different outcome variables? I aim to determine how much more likely, on average, models including effect X are at producing the observed data compared to models without it.
